# Discover "true" size of /proc/mounts

Tags: linux

At the moment, I can determine when /proc/mounts changes using `poll` and the revents `POLLERR | POLLPRI`. I would now like to be able to compare the size of this pseudo-file before and after changing to determine whether a new mount has been attached, or an old one removed.

I have tried to use `ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &size)`, but it seems to report a nonsense size. I *don't want* to have to buffer the entire output, because I would have to allocate quite a large buffer which wouldn't be portable.

I am  writing a C/C++ application which can listen and respond to mount-point changes. More specifically, when a USB mass-storage device is attached to the system, I want my program to be able to:

1. Identify that a new partition has been mounted.
2. Check the contents of that partition.
3. If the partition contains a file with a particular name, do something with that file.

I believe that my current approach is unsuitable.

Comment: I think your safest course of action is to rescan all filesystems every time your poll wakes up.  It could be that, in rapid succession, `/dev/sdd` was unmounted, disconnected, a new drive was attached which was also assigned to `/dev/sdd`, and it was mounted on the same directory, and your process didn't get woken up until after all this had happened.  Then `/proc/mounts` may look exactly the same, but maybe the newly mounted device does contain your magic file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is conceivable that the mounts have changed but `/proc/mounts` file size stays the same. The file size is not a robust summary of the file contents.

> I don't want to have to buffer the entire output, because I would have to allocate quite a large buffer which wouldn't be portable.

Read the file character-by-character or line-by-line and make a hash of all characters (hash of the file contents). Compare the current hash with the previous one to determine whether the file contents have changed.

---

Your application can parse `/proc/mounts` or `/proc/self/mountinfo`,  build a sorted list of mounts (e.g. mount-point and major-minor) and keep it. When `/proc/mounts` is updated, parse again and build a new sorted list, compare it with the kept one to determine mount additions/removals, act on the additions/removals, replace the kept list with the new one.

Comment: Of course, if you actually want to know *what* has changed, not just that *something* has changed, I don't think there is any good way around actually storing the previous contents (or at least those entries you care about), and comparing.  I don't understand what would be non-portable about that.

Comment: Okay, so this doesn't seem like the way to go. What is the proper way to react to mount changes in C on a Linux system?

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut: Maybe you should explain more fully what changes you are watching for, and why, and what you want to do when something changes.  At present this sounds a lot like an XY problem.

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut: Also, are you aware of `getmntent`, which is a more portable alternative to parsing `/proc/mounts`?

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut Waiting for changes on `/proc/mounts` with `select/poll/epoll_wait` is well-defined. You can parse `/proc/self/mountinfo` instead of `/proc/mounts`, the former is `scanf` friendly.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin You'll notice that my question already says I use poll to detect overall changes. This does not help in monitoring the pseudo-file for useful, usable changes.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Ah `/proc/self/mountinfo` might be suitable. How can I find out whether a proc file is `scanf`-friendly or not?

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut Updated the answer for you.

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut In `man proc` look for: _This file contains formation about mount points.  It **contains lines of the form**:_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199643/discussion-between-benjamin-crawford-ctrl-alt-tut-and-maxim-egorushkin).